# Is it less computationally intensive to use 7.0 or float(7) in Python?

Tags: python, types

I'm curious which form is more efficient, is correct style, etc. I feel like the ".0" approach is much quicker; I'm not sure why the "float" approach is equally appreciated (if it is).

Comment: Accept the answer below if you found it to be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `float(7)` adds some unnecessary overhead—Python has to find the `float` function in `globals()` and call it. Using `7.0` does all the necessary conversions at compile-time instead of run-time. You can see this using the [Python bytecode disassembler](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html).

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(): return 7.0
... 
>>> def g(): return float(7)
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (7.0)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(g)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (float)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (7)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 9):

use the `7.0` approach, the `float(7)` approach is used to transform integer or string types to floats so it's a different use, for example:

```
a = 7
b = "7"
print float(a)
7.0
print float(b)
7.0
```

Comment: Ah I see its use now. Thank you!

Comment: `float()` incurs some overhead as well.

Answer (score 6):

The following are all equivalent in Python:

```
>>> 7. == 7.0 == float(7) == float("7")
True
```

I would avoid using `float(7)` or `float("7")` when you are hard-coding the value, as the Python interpreter must first cast the value to an integer or a string, and then convert it to floating-point.

To avoid that overhead, use `7.` or `7.0` to give Python a float literal.

Of course, `float()` should still be used to convert other data types to a float.

Answer (score 1):

Float literals can be written as `7.0`, that is fine as they are automatically of type `float`.

If you intend to convert an integer or string to float then the `float()` function is appropriate but that function does not need to be called to write a float literal.

Answer (score 0):

7.0 is "better", no need for the cast to float, it will do it automatically.

float() is best saved for casting a non-float to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Using `float(0)` is much more explicit when re-reading your code at a later date, causing less confusion later if you accidentally drop the "`.0`".

Comment: How exactly does one accidentally drop that?

Comment: @MichaelHoffman Say you have `this_should_be_a_float = 7.0/denominator`, where denominator is an int.  My thinking was that for future maintainability it might be nice to have a very explicit way to point out that the `7.0` needed to be a float in order to not have a rounding issue in case someone later changed the 7.0 to another constant, such as 6, and forgot to add the ".0".

Comment: You should use `from __future__ import division` if you aren't already. Then this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`7.0` should be faster.  `float(7)` creates an integer, then call the `float()` function to convert the integer to a float, so calling `float(7)` implicates function call overhead as well as any error checking the `float()` function might do.

For most practical purposes, of course, the difference in speed is unlikely to matter much (unless you're in a deep loop where your code is being called hundreds of millions of times), but there's something inelegant about invoking a conversion function when the interpreter has a built in syntax for constructing floats.

Use `float()` when you have something that isn't a float (like a string or an integer) that you want to convert.